# Migration from GAPE python25 to python 27

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an application which use Google AppEngine (python 2.5) features on ubuntu server. 
The application was developed by python 2.6.

Here example:

```
# Google API Loading for apache mod_wsgi
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch_stub
from google.appengine.api import mail_stub
from google.appengine.api import user_service_stub
from google.appengine.api.memcache import memcache_stub


from google.appengine.ext import webapp
class Class1(webapp.RequestHandler)
```

Should I migrate asap to python2.7? What Google deprecation policy for python2.5 for my case , exact time please?

Note I have already migrated Google AppEngine application python2.5 to 2.7 which is deployed in GAPE.
Regards

Comment: I would ASAP. Google can stop support without much warning. They have a guide that should help: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27

Comment: Thanks a lot fir your feedback. Is there any communication about deprecation policy which contains exat date to stop support?

Comment: Not that I could find but there is an email you could contact to see if they have a date. google-appengine-python25-deprecation@googlegroups.com

Comment: Hi,I aleardy used this link to migrate google appengine application to python27. the application works correctly with python 27 on GAPE production environement. But now I would like to migrate application using google appengine env on unix server. Is there any documentation that can help me? (I followed the instructions described in that link but I faced some issues) Thanks in advance

Comment: Unix server on a third party and not on GCE